# Two embedded symplectic spheres with zero square in a symplectic $4$-manifold

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

I am aware that the following result is a classical one (by now). But I am not able to understand who proved it. What should be a proper reference to this statement?

**Theorem**. Let $M^4$ be a compact symplectic manifold with $\pi_1\ne 0$ and let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two symplectic spheres embedded in it with $S_1^2=S_2^2=0$. Then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are symplectically isotopic in $M^4$.

In other words, is there an article/book (say pre 2000) claiming that any two symplectic spheres with zero self-intersection in an irrational ruled (non-minimal) surface are symplectically isotopic?

Comment: By a result of McDuff (*The structure of rational and ruled symplectic 4-manifolds*), $M$ is a blow-up of either $\mathbb{C}P^2$ or of a ruled manifold (i.e. the total space of an $S^2$-fibration). You might find an answer to your question in her (and Lalonde's) related works, which focus on spheres and isotopies of symplectic forms on these manifolds.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I went through all the theorems and lemmas in this article but was not able to find the statement... I suspect that the statement can be in the book of McDuff and Salamon on J-holomorphic curves but was not able to get hold of it. Otherwise I know one place from 2010 where this fact is stated, but of course it should be something much earlier...

Comment: The reason you can't find the statement is that it's false. $S^2 \times S^2$, with the standard symplectic structure, has two symplectic spheres of square 0 that are not (smoothly) isotopic.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I forgot to say that $\pi_1(M)\ne 0$, it is corrected. And this  is still not in the article of McDuff. Do you think you know the reference now?

Comment: Paolo Lisca and I proved something very similar on Page 29 of *On Stein ﬁllings of contact torus bundles* (Bull. LMS 48, 2016), within the proof of Theorem 3.5. I think that there is an argument using adjunction alone as well. (Both arguments use McDuff's theorem, as mentioned by Chris above.)

Comment: Thanks Marco, I would guess, the result I am looking for was proven before 2000.

Comment: No doubt about it! I guess my point was that we weren't aware (back when Paolo and I wrote the paper) of any reference, and we proved it by hand. I'm sure people knew the statement in fibre bundles before McDuff, which probably makes it hard to find it explicitly written. Have you tried Chris Wendl's notes on McDuff's theorem (and surroundings)?

Answer (score 2):

It looks indeed that this question is not as classical is it sounds, so let me provide a  2010 reference to a more general statement, at least to show that there is a reference. This is Proposition 3.2 in the following paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4146

Answer (score 0):

Partial attempt of answer if $M$ is minimal. Since $S_1$ is an embedded sphere, there exists a diffeomorphism $e_i:M(J,S_i)\times_GS^2\rightarrow M, i=1,2$ (see 1) induced by the evaluation map.

Since $\pi_1(M)$ is not trivial, the base of the fibration is a surface of genus $>0$. The Serre exact sequence of the fibration shows that $\pi_2(M)$ is generated by $\pi_2(S_1)=\pi_1(S_2)$ and the Hurewicz morphism implies that the classes $[S_1]$ of $[S_2]$ are equal in $H_2(M)$.  We deduce that $[S_1].[S_2]=0$ and $S_1\cap S_2$ is empty.  This implies that $S_2$ coincide with the  fibre of $e_1$ which contains one of its point. We can also say that since $[S_1]=[S_2]$, $S_2$ is realized by $e_1$.  We deduce that  there is a symplectic isotopy between $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Introduction to symplectic topology p. 185 vi) McDuff and Solomon.

Comment: The existence of the diffeomorphism $e_i$ requires that $M$ be minimal (which is not assumed, here). Moreover, it's not true that $H_2$ of an irrational ruled surface has one generator; e.g. $H_2(\Sigma\times S^2) = \mathbb{Z}^2$, generated by a section and a fibre. (This is true for all bundles, actually.)

Comment: Minimality is not mentioned in the reference above.

Comment: I can't find the reference you are giving in McDuff and Salamon. In any case, if you blow-up $\Sigma\times S^2$, then you still have plenty of 0-spheres, but the 4-manifold is not a fibre bundle (not even topologically). (Relative) minimality is a key assumption in McDuff's theorem.